# htaccess blocks the php scripts running on the host server

Tags: php, .htaccess

On a PHP server, I have a htaccess like this one :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.com/.*$ [NC]
ReWriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$ - [F]
```

The problem : the htaccess is blocking also the php script which needs to use the pictures, like for instance :

```
$photo = "http://mywebsite.com/img/00001.jpg";
$NewImg= imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
```

I get the following error message :

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(http://mywebsite.com/img/00001.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/mywebsite/img/00001.jpg on line 2
```

I have not clue how to adjust the htaccess file to allow the host server to use the local pistures.

Some suggestions ?

Comment: If the PHP script is running on the same server as where the images are stored, you can load the image in via a local path instead of via a HTTP request.

Comment: Why I did not think about it before !!!!!!!!!!! It seems to work... I will check with the rest of the script !!!! Thanks @rickdenhaan !

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]
```

Comment: I maybe tested it incorrectly... I try to replace my htaccess file with : RewriteEngine On  RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!mywebsite/)" - [F] only... but nothing is blocked anymore. When I key "http://mywebsite.com/img/00001.jpg" in the webbrowser, the picture is not blocked (anymore). Did I test it wronghly ?

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.